# How to run Apk using Python Os system

Tags: python, apk

Is it possible to use OS System to run Android Apps if use tell how, it worked for Windows but i couldn't figure it out for Android Apps. I know this is short but i really want to know.

Comment: "Python Os"??? "OS System"??? What are you talking about?

Comment: i'm talking about os.system